# How to set the maximum allocated RAM for the java server, without stopping the server? (-Xmx)

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, ram

I can't use the java plugin to set the maximum allocated RAM to the server while it is running, but I need to make the RAM increase or decrease on the server depending on the number of players.

I tried several ways, via java.args and via runtime. Both methods do not work, it gives a big error to the console.

Comment: Why do you need to do this while it’s running?

Comment: You can't change the max heap size while a JVM is running.  It is not possible.